# How To Restore a Missing Redis Service

Tags: linux, redis, centos

I installed an older version of Redis on a CentOS server. I tried to remove that old version and update it to latest version, but it seems that the redis service is gone and the new version installation doesn't reproduce it. Is there any way I can uninstall the Redis completely and make a fresh install? Otherwise, is there any way I can reinstall Redis service? When I check service list, I see redis in the list but when I execute `service Redis restart`, it says "unrecognized service".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to remove redis old package you can use yum remove command as below.

```
yum remove redis
```

then check it still available as below

```
rpm -qi redis
```

and also check files

```
rpm -ql redis
```

if its there you can remove as below.

```
rpm -e redis
```

(or you can mention package full name with versions)

then you can install new version which you want.

```
 wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm' http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/

    rpm -Uvh dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-*.rpm
```

then run

```
yum install redis
```

or you can download rpm and install it as below

```
rpm -ivh redis-"version".rpm
```

but better to use yum because its going with all dependences.

Answer (score 0):

You might try init 1 then init 5 to take the system to single user then back to gui thus restarting all services in case your Redis is relying upon another service.  Also do this as SU.